# $\left\langle A,\leq_{A}\right\rangle $ is a totally ordered set with the property that $\{b\in A\mid b\leq_{A}a\}$ is finite for each $a \in A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Also, $\left\langle A,\leq_{A}\right\rangle $ doesn't have a maximal element.

Is it true that $\left\langle A,\leq_{A}\right\rangle $ has a minimum? (strictly because of the proprerty that  $\{b\in A\mid b\leq_{A}a\}$ is finite for each $a \in A$)?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @quasi Yes. I am not asking for a proof, more of a verification of my opinion... I think I managed to show that it is true but I am not so sure of myself.

Comment: Include why you think it's true to improve the question.

Comment: You should edit your post to show your attempt.

Comment: Well basically if I assume that there is no minimum, I can build an infinite decreasing chain from some element $b'$ which will give me a contradiction to the given property that $\{b\in A\mid b\leq_{A}b'\}$ is finite @quasi

Comment: The work is supposed to be included as part of your posted question, not just in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing $A$ is nonempty, take $a\in A$. Then $S=\{b\in A:b\le_A a\}$ is finite and totally ordered, so has a minimum $a_0$.

Now try showing that $a_0$ is the minimum of $A$. Begin by supposing $c\le_Aa_0$ for some $c\in A$, and show that $c$ must be equal to $a_0$. You will need to use transitivity of $\le_A$ as well as the property "$x\le_A y$ and $y\le_A x$ implies $x=y$."